# React useState await for state to be set

Tags: reactjs

I am converting a React Component to a function and I'm not used to React useHooks. I have converting the following from

```
handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const { orderBy, order } = this.state;
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
    this.setState(
      {
        order: isAsc ? "desc" : "asc",
        orderBy: property
      },
      this.getRows
    );
};
```

To

```
function handleRequestSort(event, property) {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
    setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
    setOrderBy(property);
    getRows();
}
```

But the problem is that now getRows() is being run before the order and orderBy states have been set screwing up my getRows functionality

Any help would be great cheers.

Comment: does the compoenent return getRow() ? where is the return statement

Comment: shouldn't getRows inside an useEffect, since it is a side effect of the order and order by changed

Comment: @WilsonLiao The component is now a function and doesn't return getRows and never has, getRows is another function not a value

Comment: @AngelSalazar I have it in useEffect for when the function first mounts, is there a way I can call it when both Order & OrderBy change not when either one changes. I don't want to call getRows() twice as it has a complicated api call in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use-state-with-callback library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-state-with-callback

```
import useStateWithCallback from 'use-state-with-callback';

const Index = () => {
    const [orderState, setOrderState] = useStateWithCallback({}, (state) => {
        const {orderBy, order} = state;
        if(order && orderBy){
            getRows()
        }
    })

    const {orderBy, order} = orderState;

    const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
        const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
        setOrderState({
            order : isAsc ? "desc" : "asc",
            orderBy : property
        })
    }

    return(...)
}
```

or

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const Index = () => {
    const [orderState, setOrderState] = useState({});

    const {orderBy, order} = orderState;

    const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
        const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
        setOrderState({
            order : isAsc ? "desc" : "asc",
            orderBy : property
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(orderBy && order){
            getRows()
        }
    },[orderState])

    return (...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I would rather just go back to using a Component then using this npm package. I don't want another unnecessary dependency that i'll have to explain to my boss

Comment: Then you can useEffect hook.

Comment: Thank you that was what I'm after that's prefect! I forgot useState can take objects

Comment: the return of useState is an array therefore `[orderState, setOrderState] = useState({})` is the correct form of usage.

Comment: Oh. Is is my mistake. Thank you @Navid